# android Images in r.raw

Tags: java, android

is there any way of forcing app to install in SD card.
i have user User permission in manifest file
but still drawable and database is coped in internal memory.

then i came to know that that only RAW folder will be saved in SD card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force the App to be installed on the SD Card for the simple reason, that if the SD Card is full the installation would crash. All you can do is this:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

in your Manifest.